# work around keyword by calling same procedure?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

since the continue keyword wont work coz of the following reason  I  tried to make this work around by calling same procedure and passing the next value from the record to it 
so is that right way ??

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 26: PLS-00201: identifier 'CONTINUE' must be
>   declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 26: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

```
declare 
cust_id info.CUSTOMER_ID@prod%type;
V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID FEB_PRD_14_VIEW.CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID@rtx%type;
V_INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP FEB_PRD_14_VIEW.INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP@rtx%type;

cursor rated_rejectes_calls_cursor is 
select S_P_NUM,CALL_START_TIME
from fi_sdine.rejected_calls_87@prod 
where UPPER (STATUS)='RATED';

begin
for rated_rejectes_calls_rec in rated_rejectes_calls_cursor
loop
if (rated_rejectes_calls_rec.S_P_NUM is not null) then

begin

select CUSTOMER_ID into cust_id from bmh.info@prod where dn_num=rated_rejectes_calls_rec.S_P_NUM;

if (V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID is null ) then
select CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID, INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP into V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID,V_INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP 
from FI_MASAAD.FEB_PRD_14_VIEW@rtx a
where  CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID =cust_id
and INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP=rated_rejectes_calls_rec.CALL_START_TIME 
group by CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID,INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('null NOT Found '||V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID);

end if;

dbms_output.put_line('The customer ID for S_P_NUM '||rated_rejectes_calls_rec.S_P_NUM||' is '||cust_id|| ' and the call start time is  '||rated_rejectes_calls_rec.CALL_START_TIME||' has been found' );
dbms_output.put_line('The customer ID'||V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID||' and call start is '||V_INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP);

exception 

when no_data_found then
dbms_output.put_line('The Customer ID NOT FOUND FOR S_P_NUM '|| rated_rejectes_calls_rec.S_P_NUM);
 --contunie;
-- recall procedure and pass the next value to same procedure ?
exec check_rejected_CDRs(rated_rejectes_calls_rec.nextval);

end;
end if;
end loop;
end;
end check_rejected_CDRs;
```

Comment: i don't see the word `CONTINUE` int he code and i don't understand your problem.

Comment: code update it ... coz  I replace it with recalling procedure

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your exception handler in the wrong place.
I *think* you are trying to achieve this....

```
declare

cust_id info.CUSTOMER_ID@prod%type;
V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID FEB_PRD_14_VIEW.CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID@rtx%type;
V_INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP FEB_PRD_14_VIEW.INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP@rtx%type;

cursor rated_rejectes_calls_cursor is 
select S_P_NUM,CALL_START_TIME
from fi_sdine.rejected_calls_87@prod 
where UPPER (STATUS)='RATED';

begin
for rated_rejectes_calls_rec in rated_rejectes_calls_cursor
loop
    if (rated_rejectes_calls_rec.S_P_NUM is not null) then

    begin

         select CUSTOMER_ID into cust_id from bmh.info@prod where dn_num=rated_rejectes_calls_rec.S_P_NUM;

         if (V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID is null ) then

            BEGIN 



            select CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID, INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP into V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID,V_INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP
            from FI_MASAAD.FEB_PRD_14_VIEW@rtx a
            where  CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID=cust_id
            and INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP=rated_rejectes_calls_rec.CALL_START_TIME
            group by CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID,INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('null NOT Found '||V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID);
```

EXCEPTION
                when no_data_found then
                    dbms_output.put_line('The Customer ID NOT FOUND FOR S_P_NUM '|| rated_rejectes_calls_rec.S_P_NUM);
                    exec check_rejected_CDRs(rated_rejectes_calls_rec.nextval);
                END;

```
         end if;

         dbms_output.put_line('The customer ID for S_P_NUM '||rated_rejectes_calls_rec.S_P_NUM||' is '||cust_id|| ' and the call start time is  '||rated_rejectes_calls_rec.CALL_START_TIME||' has been found' );
         dbms_output.put_line('The customer ID'||V_CUST_INFO_CUSTOMER_ID||' and call start is '||V_INITIAL_START_TIME_TIMESTAMP);

    end;

    end if;

end loop;

end;

end check_rejected_CDRs;
```

Comment: the exception block should be the last block of code I believe that this code wont work... but i tested and it gives an exception

Comment: The exception block does not have to be the last block of code. It is common practice in PL/SQL to trap specific errors in code using localised exception handling.
By doing this - the code can log an error - handle an exception and continue processing.

You are of course, welcome to add another error handler at the end of your code.

Comment: thanks about ur useful info but this code throw  the following exception ORA-06550: line 35, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: Its a typo - have editted it but - you'll need to put ...

EXCEPTION

WHEN no_data_found

Comment: then we back to the first question i am getting error [Error] PLS-00103 (39: 26): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CHECK_REJECTED_CDRS" when expecting one of the following:
 think this way is not applicable  
   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "CHECK_REJECTED_CDRS" to continue.